# water tank modeling in simscape

Tags: matlab, oop, modeling, simulink, simscape

I want to model a simple tank with water flowing out of it.
Which has level sensor and connected to a controller.
When the sensor gets activated(means minimum value of tank has been reached), it sends signal to Actuator to stop the outflow. I have questions:

1)how to create a hydraulic domain with one outflow port ?

2)How to create a tank model?

3)How to create level sensor?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks